# Compare the value of a variable at intervals

Tags: objective-c, struct, copy, compare, point

Hey I have a problem comparing the value of a CGPoint (struct with two ints: x and y) with another at certain time intervals.

One is called location and has the value of where the cursor is. Every half a second or so, I want to see if it changed. How do I do this? The language is Objective-C (so C++/C stuff should work)

Comment: If you can read the location, then you can save it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do with this? Would it make more sense to use Key Value Observing to observe when one or both values change?

Comment: I'm trying to check when the user keeps his finger at the same spot, and only increment a variable ticks when the finger has moved.

Comment: The four touches*:withEvent: methods of UIResponder should help you, particularly touchesMoved:withEvent:

Comment: Wow...I was even using those functions. Just had to put ticks += 10 in the touchesMoved:withEvent one. I feel stupid...

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the CGGeometry docs, Apple provides a function, `CGPointEqualToPoint()`, for doing just this. You would have a CGPoint variable that stores the old value and compare it to the new value you get.

Comment: Yes, but I'm wondering how to temporarily store the value of a CGPoint and compare it later.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the NSTimer documentation.  It does what you want.

Comment: I'm using that. The problem is storing the value of the touch location and not updating it.